# Responsive Design. Grid layout for floating divs, but one exception

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, grid

maybe it´s a tricky question, maybe not. I have a grid layout with floating divs. I would like to build a responsive design. When you adjust the size of the browser window the divs will float in the hidden area. This is easy.

BUT what i try is that the last "more" div will always be the last div in the grid.

Heres the example code

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
    <div id="1" class="square">1</div>
        <div id="2" class="square">2</div>
        <div id="3" class="square">3</div>
        <div id="4" class="square">4</div>
        <div class="more">more</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.more {
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
background: red;
color: #000;
text-align: center; 
float: left;
}

div.container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
}

div.square {
position: relative;
background: green;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
}

div.bar {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background: #000;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here i have a simple fiddle Demo. When you adjust the grid, the divs are floating. But the last more div is also floating, which is not what i need here.

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2s4zr470/3/)

Can this be done by pure css or is js needed? Thank you for any help.

Ruven

Comment: not too sure i understood, but is this alike what you look for ? http://jsfiddle.net/2s4zr470/5/

Comment: @GCyrillus I am pretty sure OP wants it like my answer, float right works kind of but when the page is large it looks funny.

Comment: @GCyrillus oh yep, I thought so lol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use media queries like this http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/2s4zr470/4/

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
    <div id="one" class="square">1</div>
        <div id="two" class="square">2</div>
        <div id="three" class="square">3</div>
        <div id="four" class="square">4</div>
        <div class="more">more</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.more {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        background: red;
        color: #000;
        float: right;
        text-align: center; 
        float: left;

    }

div.container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
    }

div.square {
        position: relative;
        background: green;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

 div.bar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        background: #000;
    }
@media (max-width: 340px){
    #four{display: none;}

}
@media (max-width: 280px){
    #three{display: none;}

}
@media (max-width: 220px){
    #two{display: none;}

}
@media (max-width: 160px){
    #one{display: none;}

}
```

Comment: Oh wow, i never used them. I´am new to responsive design. But this is exactly what i was searching for. Thank you man. You saved me much time!

Comment: just to know is there another way or a shorter, "automated" way, when i have e.g. 9 squares + the more one. Thank you.